# Tesseract couldn't load any languages

Tags: macos, homebrew, ghostscript, tiff, tesseract-ocr

Running `tesseract makebox` command produced me the following error

`Error opening data file /opt/local/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.`

The command I used

`tesseract eng.HighwayGothic.exp0.tif eng.HighwayGothic.exp0 batch.nochop makebox`

Linked Tif file which was produced using `GhostScript` - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97646145/Issue/Onepage_TIFF.zip

When I accessed the folder tessdata of path `/opt/local/share/tessdata/`, there weren't any trainneddata. I guess, this is how we load languages

`brew install tesseract --all-languages`

Comment: On Linux first I checked if package was installed (`dpkg -l | grep tesseract` and search for install: `apt search tesseract | grep -B1 language`). I was using an invalid ISO 639-2 (three letters) language code.